# Can I inject a div that always appears above existing divs?

Tags: css, safari-extension

Relative CSS noob here.

I'm writing a Safari extension that, when its toolbar button is clicked, pops up a 'dialog banner' (some text and a couple of buttons) in the web page. The banner is a div that I inject into the page on demand, in the extension's End Script.

Question is, how to style the div (or is it even possible to do so) so that it's guaranteed to be visible regardless of the existing web page content, over which I have no control? By creating my div as `position:fixed`, and inserting it into the DOM as the first child of `<body>`, it works fine in most cases, floating at the top of the window regardless of the page's current scroll position.

However, it fails on some pages that have a header banner of their own -- for example, http://planet.gnome.org and http://www.ign.com. In these cases, my div is obscured by the page banner. Adjusting the `z-index` of my div doesn't make any difference.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, or is it just the case that I'll never be able to predict how other people's web pages are structured, so I should find a different way to present my UI?

Comment: At what position in the DOM do you inject the div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tqfna/1/ Aren't the obscuring elements flash banners? They have a `wmode` attribute which can make funny things.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm injecting the div as the first child node of the <body>.

Comment: @biziclop There's definitely no Flash/wmode stuff on the planet.gnome.org website, at least… it's a free/open source software project and they'd have a fit if there was any Flash on there :) I hadn't noticed the wmode attributes on the IGN website, though, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @biziclop (And thanks for the fiddle, will investigate that shortly.)

Comment: If you want to guarantee "above-ness", then I think you will have to use some javascript to find the max z-index. I just realized that my fiddle should work recursively to really find all offending z-indexes OR set `position:relative` for every `position:static` direct child of the body.

Comment: @biziclop I'll have a play with that idea, although manually setting the z-index to some arbitrarily high value like 9999 didn't seem to make any difference when I tried it before.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tqfna/2/

Comment: @biziclop Nice, thanks. Think I've got to the bottom of this now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out it this *was* basically just a simple z-index problem, which I can solve either statically or by using something like @biziclop's dynamic approach. I thought I'd exhausted that line of investigation before I posted, but apparently not… partly due to a stray `!important` in my stylesheet that was masking my attempts to fix. D'oh.